# New request with axios if the first does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

i made this function that makes a request to the API based on the past parameters, only if it returns an error i want a **NEW REQUEST** to be made only by changing the value of the **URL** that i pass, removing a parameter, it's possible? Below is what i tried but failed

```
try {
    const URL = 'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make='+make+'&model='+model+'&year='+year+'&pid=2&ptid=41&body='+body;
        let res = await axios.get(URL);
        
        if (res.data.statusCode == 404) {
            URL = 'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make='+make+'&model='+model+'&year='+year+'&pid=2&ptid=41';
            res = await axios.get(URL);
    
            return res.data.data;
        } else {
            return res.data.data;
        }  
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
```

I realized that I can't get the *statusCode* because they are falling in **Catch(err)**, so how can I do to make a new request if the first is *not accepted*?

**SOLUTION:**

```
try {
      const URL = 'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make='+make+'&model='+model+'&year='+year+'&pid=2&ptid=41&body='+body;
      let res = await axios.get(URL); 
      return res.data.data;
     
    } catch (err) {
      try { 
           // New request
           const URL = 'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make='+make+'&model='+model+'&year='+year+'&pid=2&ptid=41';
           let res = await axios.get(URL);
           return res.data.data;
      } catch (err) {
           return err;
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to get the satus code then should not be any error but the response. If the call throw an error will not have the status code (which is sent in the response).

Comment: I want it when it lands on Catch (err), when it fails to make the first request, I want it to change the URL value and make a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only what you describe of one request being failed you want the second to start then call the second one inside the first catch

```js
try {

    const URL = 'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make=' + make + '&model=' + model + '&year=' + year + '&pid=2&ptid=41&body=' + body;

    let res = await axios.get(URL);

    return res.data.data;

} catch (err) {

    console.error(err);

    try {
      URL = 'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make=' + make + '&model=' + model + '&year=' + year + '&pid=2&ptid=41';
      res = await axios.get(URL);

      return res.data.data;
    }
    catch(error){
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

if you have many urls, and you want to keep requesting if the first failed and keep goind until the end you can do something like this

```js
const urls = [
    'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make=' + make + '&model=' + model + '&year=' + year + '&pid=2&ptid=41&body=' + body,
    'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles?make=' + make + '&model=' + model + '&year=' + year + '&pid=2&ptid=41',
    'any more urls...'
];

async function callingUrlsInSequence(urls) {

    let i = 0;

    while (i < urls.length) {
        const url = urls[i];

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            // break the loop and return from function if the request succeed
            return response;

            // otherwise we keep looping...
        } catch (error) {

            console.error('The Url: ' + url + ' Failed!')
            continue;

        } finally {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, this request is inside an async await function, I'm using nodejs, if I throw something inside catch it generates an error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, gave me an idea and put it into practice, your second solution is great

Comment: you are right, we need to wrap `try...catch` around the call site in the catch block too, I'll update the answer